# Why does Magento have a layout XML media_type meta tag which outputs nothing?

Tags: magento2, layout, meta-tags

In the [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_meta), Magento details the possible `meta` tag names available to include in the head layout XML. The explanation for the `media_type` tag caught my eye:

> This tag will not render (see \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer for details)

Indeed, when checking the class mentioned, it looks like the `media_type` tag will not output anything:

```php
case 'media_type':
    $metadataTemplate = false;
    break;
```

What is the reason for including this in both the documentation and in the code, if there is no output rendered?

Comment: Danny did you find anything?